# Which of Naruto's forms are capable of destroying planets?

Tags: naruto

There are many forms of Naruto, and I know that most of them can destroy a moon, but a moon isn't even close to the size of a planet. At what point does Naruto become powerful enough to destroy planets? I know he could destroy the moon when he was 11 or 12 using Kyuubi mode. I know that at some point in shippuden that naruto can destroy a planet. He just never uses the full extent of this power.

Comment: Do you know for certain that Naruto *does* become capable of destroying an entire planet?

Comment: I do in fact know that Naruto eventually reaches that level.

Comment: If you've found an answer to your question, please post it as an answer so you can accept it. (It would also be a good idea to include the evidence that led you to this conclusion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't be able to give all the answers, but nevertheless I'll try-

- Jubilo
- Jubidara
- Kaguya (at any point after absorbing the god tree)
- SOSP Sasuke
- Indra Mode Sasuke
- The Last Sasuke
- Boruto Sasuke
- KCM2 Naruto
- SOSP Naruto
- Ashura Mode Naruto
- The Last Naruto
- KCM 3 Naruto
- KCM 4 Naruto
- KCM Final Naruto (At this point he could destroy literally anything, he was undefeatable)

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! The question is specifically about the forms of Naruto Uzumaki himself, not the forms of anyone from *Naruto*, but I suppose you do deserve credit for going above and beyond what was asked for.

Comment: I accept this answer cause it does answer the question but I was only talking about Naruto.